# Will_Paginate gem error undefined method "total_pages"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

The will_paginate gem isn't working after I changed a query to get followers/followed_users

How can I use will_paginate with this??

```
@users = @user.reverse_relationships.order("created_at DESC").collect { |r| User.find(r.follower) }
```

I've tried several options like:

```
@users = @user.reverse_relationships.order("created_at DESC").collect { |r| User.find(r.follower) }
@users = @users.paginate(:page => params[:page])

@users = @user.reverse_relationships.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order("created_at DESC").collect { |r| User.find(r.follower) }
```

Each time I get an error like `undefined method "total_pages"` or `undefined method "paginate"`

Comment: likely because your object is no longer an ActiveRecord::Relation, which is what will_paginate hangs off. Also, paginating before ordering is a bit silly. Why are you doing this `collect`, why are your associations not structured correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186963/order-users-based-on-when-the-relationship-was-created-at

Comment: As you can see my original question from that post, I wanted to get a user's followers and followed_users and be able to order them based on when that relationship was created. I prefer just using my `@users.followers` and `@users.followed_users` but this doesn't put them in order of when the relationship was created. Thus, I got the answer from the other Post and wanted to paginate it. If there is a better answer, then I'd love to know though.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-order your query so that you can call `paginate` and `total_pages` on an ActiveRecord::Relation instance, as will_paginate requires.

This would remove the `collect` which effectively turns your relation into an array.

This could be done with something like:

```
@relationships = @user.reverse_relationships.includes(:follower).order("created_at DESC")
```

And then just access the follower of each relationship in your view or whatnot.

This will also be more efficient - you won't be issuing a separate query for each follower, as your original code is doing.

Comment: That's giving me `wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)`

Comment: gack, I always forget if its `include` or `includes`. Should probably be `includes` then :)